# VS Code code pane will not go full width (has gutters)

Tags: visual-studio-code

For only one of my VS Code projects, the code pane will not extend to the full width of the editor window. I have tried removing all VS Code settings (user and workspace settings) as well as starting up VS Code with no extensions and this single project still will not expand to full-width. It's behaving like the a multi-code pane - pane, but with only a single pane.

[VS Code shown with gutters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsFlc.png)

Answer (score 5):

The described view rendering on VSCode is due to choosing the default `Centered Layout`.

The solution was to change the following from the Menu Bar on Visual Studio:

`View` --> `Appearance` --> Uncheck the `Centered Layout` option.